# How to differentiate between vpa and sym in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

The title says it already. Given three variables:

```
d = 2;
s = sym(2);
v = vpa(2);
```

How can I identify which variable is of which type. Clearly, to identify doubles I can do `isa( d, 'double' )`. But all methods I know to identify symbolic variables do not differentiate between `vpa` and `sym`, e.g. `isa( s, 'sym' )` and `isa( v, 'sym' )` both return `true`.

Comment: `vpa` produces a result of type `sym`. So there is no difference. They are of the same type

Comment: Thus my question. Conceptually they are very different --- sym(2) stores the number exact; vpa(2) is a floating point number.

Comment: `vpa(2)` is a `sym`

Comment: @LuisMendo, No, vpa is floating point number, see: the documentation or try: `isAlways((vpa('2')+vpa('1e-100000'))==sym(2))`

Comment: `vpa` is from the symbolic math toolbox and its result is also symbolic. Sym is a class. Doesn't matter you store a floating point number or an integer with it

Comment: @SardarUsama Is my question really un-understandable?

Comment: No. Just that your understanding of `sym` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vpa(2)` is a sym as pointed out by [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) in the comments <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705177/how-to-differentiate-between-vpa-and-sym-in-matlab/63722336#comment112651580_63705177), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705177/how-to-differentiate-between-vpa-and-sym-in-matlab/63722336#comment112676760_63705177)</sup>.

What you are looking for is [**`isSymType`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.issymtype.html) (introduced in R2019a).

```
isSymType(s,'integer')
isSymType(v,'vpareal')
```

Comment: Yes exactly, do you know of a method which works in R2016a or R2018a?

Answer (score -1):

By exploiting that `vpa` is a floating point number, one can do the following in Matlab R2018b and older:

```
isAlways( s+10^sym(-100000)==s )
isAlways( v+10^sym(-100000)==v )
```

The first returns false, the second true.

---

Unfortunately, it seems this does not work in Matlab R2020a anymore.